# Pick out country code and corresponding domain from text file

Tags: php, regex, fopen, readfile

I have a text file like:

```
en-US -> www.google.co.uk
en-UK -> www.bbc.co.uk
es-CO -> www.somedomain.com
```

I want to be able to pick out the country/language type for example en-US and the corresponding domain name on the same line. How do I do this?

A start:

```
 $file = "data.txt";
 $f = fopen($file, "r");

 while ( $line = fgets($f, 1000) ) {

   if (preg_match('/^-> .*$/', $line)) {
      fwrite($out, $fh);
   }
   print $line;
 }
```

Comment: substr($line, 0, strpos($line, '->')); Seems to pick out the language/Country code only. How do I pick out the domain and country/language code separateley?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
list($code, $domain) = array_map('trim', explode('->', $line, 2));
```

- Split line by `->` into two parts
- Remove leading / ending spaces
- Extract as variables

Comment: This works but for some reason I get the error: Undefined offset: 1

Comment: Its because one of the lines didnt have -> Is there a way for php to not throw and error or simply ignore the line if '->' hasent been found?

Comment: Add a check: `if(strpos($line, '<-') !== false){ ...`

Answer (score 0):

Why do that when you could just use an existing format and get better control:

Ini file

```
en_US = www.google.co.uk
en_UK = www.bbc.co.uk
es_CO = www.somedomain.com
```

PHP

```
$domains = parse_ini_file('data.ini');

print_r($domains);
```

PHP Output

```
Array(
  'en_US' => 'www.google.co.uk',
  'en_UK' => 'www.bbc.co.uk',
  'es_CO' => 'www.somedomain.com'
)
```

Comment: This is a pretty neat way to do it.